# Arcgis: How can I load an image as the map?

Tags: wpf, gis, arcgis

I am using Arcgis WPF, I am wondering if I could load an image as the map in my application? If it is possible, could you please tell me how to achieve it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageServer for the imagery files, and if the image is an .jpeg or .png and is non georeferenced, then you can use ArcMap to make it a map service (tiled map service or dynamic map service) and then use that map service in your code. You can go to ArcGIS online forums for WPF for more information

Answer (score 0):

Is it satellite imagery or just an image?  What API are you using?

If it is just an image, you can use a [Graphics Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/help/index.html#/Creating_a_graphics_layer/01n700000019000000/) and add the image as a graphic.  With this approach, you can give it whatever lat/lon makes sense for your spatial reference.

If you have satellite imagery, you want to add it as a Raster layer (ArcGIS for Desktop/Engine) or a Tiled Map Service (WPF/Silverlight APIs).  If you are using the WPF API's (and not ArcGIS Engine) then this requires access to ArcGIS Server to publish a map service.

I recommend reading through the [API documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/help/index.html#//01n700000015000000) as it is well documented.